# Two Assert.AreEqual() comparisons, depending on the input value

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I want to check for equality between an enum I created and an input value from a file. It should be one of 3 values and in one case, 2 of these values essentially mean the same thing.

```
enum myEnum { ver1, ver2, ver3};
```

The code is simplified a bit, but the meaning is the same. I want to test something like the following:

```
Assert.AreEqual(ver1, x) || Assert.AreEqual(ver2, x); //Clearly doesn't work, but this is what I'd like to accomplish
Assert.AreEqual(ver3, x);
```

To be clear, these values only mean the same thing in the scope of this one test, they mean slightly different things elsewhere, so `ver1 != ver2`.

Comment: `Assert.IsTrue(ver1 == x || ver2 == x);`?

Comment: i would write two different test methods. one per assert.

Comment: What is the type of x? if it is a string "ver1"..."ver3", you can use Enum.Parse to convert the names to enum types for comparison; if x is integer, you can do a simple cast (myEnum)x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution for this is to not use Assert for the check, but for the fail.

```
if (x != ver1 && x != ver2) {
    Assert.Fail("x not equal to ver1 or ver2")
}
```